# ANTLR4 tells me: mismatched input 'little' expecting {'big', 'little'}

Tags: antlr4

I have the following simple grammar:

```
grammar TestG;

p : pDecl+ ;

pDecl : endianDecl
    | dTDecl
    ;

endianType : E_BIG
    | E_LITTLE
    ;

endianDecl : 'endian' '=' endianType ';' ;

dTDecl : 'dT' '[' STRING ']' '=' ID ';' ;

STRING: '"'.*?'"' ;                //Embedded quotes?
COMMENT: '#' .*? [\n\r] -> skip ;  // Discard comments for now
ID :   [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]* ;
WS :   [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;
INT : ('0x')?[0-9]+ ;  // How to handle 0xDD and ensure non zero?
E_BIG : 'big' ;
E_LITTLE : 'little' ;
```

When I run `grun TestG p` and input the following:

```
endian = little;
```

I get the following:

```
line 1:9 mismatched input 'little' expecting {'big', 'little'}
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Is there something about my answer that could be improved to get you to Accept it?

Comment: It wasn't clear to me that I needed to accept the answer ... the UI was not intuitive to me. However, I did try it and it fixes the problem, so thanks. I have now marked it as the answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your lexer rule for `ID` precedes that for `E_LITTLE`, your 'little' input is being lexed as an `ID`.

```
[@0,0:5='endian',<'endian'>,1:0]
[@1,7:7='=',<'='>,1:7]
[@2,9:14='little',<ID>,1:9] <== see here it's being lexed as an ID
[@3,15:15=';',<';'>,1:15]
[@4,18:17='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
line 1:9 mismatched input 'little' expecting {'big', 'little'}
```

Moving the these lexer tokens **above** ID like so:

```
STRING: '"'.*?'"' ;                //Embedded quotes?
COMMENT: '#' .*? [\n\r] -> skip ;  // Discard comments for now
E_BIG : 'big' ;
E_LITTLE : 'little' ;
ID :   [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]* ;
WS :   [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;
INT : ('0x')?[0-9]+ ;  // How to handle 0xDD and ensure non zero?
```

yields the correct output from your test input.

```
[@0,0:5='endian',<'endian'>,1:0]
[@1,7:7='=',<'='>,1:7]
[@2,9:14='little',<'little'>,1:9] <== see here being lexed correctly
[@3,15:15=';',<';'>,1:15]
[@4,18:17='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
```

[image]

Remember, for lexer tokens, the longest match wins, but in the case of a tie, the one that appears FIRST wins.  This is why you want your more specific lexer tokens at the top of the lexer token list, and the more general ones (like identifiers, strings, etc.) farther down.